# using grep to print specific lines in another file

Tags: unix, grep

I want to use grep command to print only those lines that contains a specific string in another file. My file is in xsls format and looks like:

[image]

I only want to extract those lines that contain 5'UTR in Annotation column.

The command I use is:

```
grep 'UTR$' Lee2012.xslx > utr.txt
```

However, I end up getting an empty file. I'll appreciate if someone can explain what I am doing wrong. Insights will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `awk '$6 ~ /UTR$/' Lee2012.xslx > utr.txt`? Your sixth columns ends with `UTR`, and not the whole line.

Comment: This produces an empty file as well.

Comment: Show an excerpt of the file.

Comment: It worked. I changed the extension from xlsx to txt and that seems to work. Thank you @WiktorStribiżew. Can you tell me why my grep command wasn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sixth column ends with `UTR`, not the whole line, that is why you get no results.

To get all lines where the sixth column ends with `UTR`, you can use

```sh
awk '$6 ~ /UTR$/' Lee2012.xslx > utr.txt
```

This assumes your column (field) separators are whitespace.